# Admob banner duplicating when refreshing

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, banner

when I refresh my AdMob banner it duplicates itself so my question is how I can clear the banner when refreshing and generate a new one?
here is an image for more clarifications.[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKemp.png)

Comment: attach your code snippet here